# NullPointerException with app in production on an api call

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I have an app in production. In my application on forgot password screen when user enters his/her mobile number, an api is being called and user gets an OTP on the entered number, the api is getting executed as it is intended to but I am getting a NullPointerException in my app in production and user is not being redirected to next screen as it should, everything works fine in debug build for testing purposes ,but in production it is throwing a NullPointerException. I can see that api call is successfull because of the print statement I have during the successful call of the api but after that message logcat shows NullPointerException. When the NullPointerException is thrown and in logcat i cannot determine where exactly is the problem as it does not suggest what part of code is responsible for NPE.

```
private void forgotPasswordApi() {
    if (Util.isConnectingToInternet(context)) {
        CommonMethods.showLoading(this);

        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        builder.addFormDataPart(Constants.MOBILE, mobileEt.getText().toString());
        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();

        RetrofitClient.getAPIService().userForgotPassword(requestBody).enqueue(new Callback<RetroResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RetroResponse> call, Response<RetroResponse> response) {
                CommonMethods.dismissLoading();
                Log.e("USER FORGOT PASSWORD","INSIDE onResponse BLOCK ");
                try {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        String user_id = response.body().getData().getUser_id();
                         startActivity(new Intent(UserForgotPasswordActivity.this, ForgotOtpVerifyActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Constants.USER_ID, user_id));

                    } else if (response.code() == 400) {
                        Log.e("USER FORGOT PASSWORD","INSIDE 400 BLOCK ");
                        Util.ShowToastMessage(context, R.string.user_not_registered);
                    } else {
                        if (response.body().getStatus() == 401) {
                            Util.ShowToastMessage(context, "Something went wrong");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RetroResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("USER FORGOT PASSWORD","INSIDE onFailure BLOCK ");
                CommonMethods.dismissLoading();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Util.ShowToastMessage(context, R.string.internet_connection);
    }
}
```

This is the exception message I am getting in logcat just below success print message :

```
    2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at c.e.a.e.a.b.m1.a(SourceFile:9)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 1585-1585/? D/StatusBar: disable<e i a s b h r c s > disable2<q i n >
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at t.b.run(SourceFile:1)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8043)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
2021-09-21 12:42:37.006 18184-18184/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

When I test my app by debug build I didn't face any such Exception , this is coming with app in production(On Google play store), Please suggest any solution or a what can be the possible reason for the Exception, Thanks.

Comment: What line do you have the NPE? Can you tell which variable is nulle ?

Comment: @ChrisNeve i cannot determine where exactly the exception is occurring in the code, because i can only manage to print some logs from the app in prosuction.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you see this weird a,b,c characters is you obfuscate your code. You need to de-obfuscate or symbolicate crash stack traces on play console. For better crash management you can use Firebase crashlytics. When you de-obfuscate your stack trace you gonna see which part is null exactly.

Comment: The app is not exactly crashing so i am not seeing anything in the crash report in play console, and I have to remove firebase crashlytics because it was not letting me generate signed apk. when I was trying to generate signed apk I was getting some error during build, So I searched for the issue and someone on the SO suggested that we can remove crashlytics from build.gradle file, so I did.